# Black lines/shadow in Cycles f12 render but not in viewport render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Please see the image below.

[image]

I get black lines when I render using F12 but not in viewport.
Is there a way to get the rendered image to be exactly the same as in the view port?

Thank you

Comment: Please post your images with BSE's image tool...

Comment: subsurf modifier with a different value in render and preview ? (just a guess...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the number of subdivisions for view and render is not the same you'll get different results when using the subsurf modifier.

Make those values the same.

[image]

Additionally, you might need to enable smooth shading.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your picture right now but one of these should work:

1. Disable compositing:

[image]

2. Disable freestyle:

[image]

3. Make sure all objects have the same value for viewport and render (eye and camera icons)

[image]